# Checked box won’t stay checked in md-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build a with multiple selections of rows in the table.
I am able to check the box but it is not staying checked.

Find the code in the below link.

[Please find the code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-multiple-forked-jltd9?file=/App.vue)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete the following lines:

```
this.setIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
    this.getUsers();
}, 1000);
```

Is there a reason you are invoking setInterval every second?
Every time you invoke that function, data are retrieved and the grid is refreshed.